# How to update particular id information in express js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, routes, put

I want to update information from by particular id from a user user collection in MongoDB. I am using ExpressJS.

Right now from my code I can only update only login user information. Being a **super admin** I want to update user's info by ID. What do I need to do here ?

Here now in my code , when **super admin** logs in he/she can only update his/her own information. I want the super admin to update user's information

```
router.put('/edit', checkAuth, function (req, res, next) {
    if(req.userData.role === 'superadmin') {
    const id = req.userData.userId;
    User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, {$set: req.body}, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {
                if (err) return res.send(err.message)
                if (doc) return res.send(doc);
            })
    } else {
        res.status(401).send(["Not authorized. Only super admin can update details."]);
    }       
});
```

How can I update user's information from the collection ?

Comment: Where is the user's  `id` you want to update ? Your code as it is passes the current user's `id` to `findOneAndUpdate`, you need to pass the user's `id` you want to update (pass it through the `req` object).

Comment: @MoadEnnagi Yes, but here when I go to edit page, I have only single url `/edit`. So  I cannot route unless a particular user;s edit option has been clicked. Then I can use something like this `/edit/:userId`. I do not want to redirect again. Is is possible to edit in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the ID of another user through the request content, in Express this can easily be achieved with a [path parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters):

```
// Example client request: PUT /edit/507f191e810c19729de860ea
router.put('/edit/:userId', checkAuth, function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.userData.role === 'superadmin') {
    const id = req.params.userId;
    User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, {$set: req.body}, ...);
  } else { /* ... */ }
});
```

If changing the request path (`/edit`) is not an option for you, you can opt to specify the target user id through the request body instead (you will also need to update the client request to pass that `id` along with your new user data):

```
router.put('/edit', checkAuth, function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.userData.role === 'superadmin') {
    const { id, ...newUserData } = req.body;
    User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, {$set: newUserData}, ...);
  } else { /* ... */ }
});
```

Comment: Sorry if this is confusing, this is the [JS destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). `newUserData` is basically `req.body` minus the `id` property (which you don't want to set in your mongodb user document).

Comment: So in this case , how can I test the API for particular id ?  This is how should I pass the end point `/edit/:userId` ?

Comment: And also where `userId` is mentioned in req ? I will throw error

Comment: solved: you id parameter was missing `const id  = req.params.userId;
 const newUserData  = req.body;
 User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, {$set: newUserData}`